# Completely weird font rendering on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, fonts

I have a custom font embedded in my iPhone app that previously has rendered perfectly (both in the simulator and on the device). Today though, when I built and ran the app on the device it suddenly looked like this:

[image: Incorrect Font Rendering]

The problem only exists when running on the physical device. I have never seen this phenomenon before; what exactly is it? The other fonts that are used in the app render perfectly as before.

Comment: I guess you already tried to remove the app from the device and install it again...

Comment: Yes, I have already deleted, cleaned and re-installed without any change.

Comment: Any chance there's a layer mask on those 2 labels?

Comment: No layer mask I'm afraid. What's remarkable is that the font renders weirdly in a consistent manner - even when used inside a UIWebView! And again the other fonts are just fine.

Comment: Wild guess, the font binary got corrupted somehow. Check your version management system for a diff on that file.

Comment: The font file is ok. As I mentioned it actually works in the simulator, and I can open the file in Font Book as well. For good measure I also deleted the font file from my Xcode project and added it again without results (deleting and cleaning along the way, obviously). Anyone else have an idea?

Comment: This looks like some of the control points of the bezier path are corrupted. I am wondering if this could be connected to float number representation.

Comment: Try cleaning the build (Command + Shift + K), if it doesn't work, have you tried it on another device? Maybe the device has something wrong?

Comment: Seems like the letters are consistenly rendered the same (i.e the e looks the same at any position). This has to do with your graphics context.

Comment: @Magnus Look at the C in "Company" and in "Article". They are not the same.

Comment: @AliHamze they are different typefaces capital C versus non-capital c.

Comment: If this is floating point math related, there might be differences between x86 (simulator) and ARM (device). What if you open the font file with FontForge (FOSS) and check for errors there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the font file which you include is corrupted by Xcode please delete the existing one and move to trash also and import new font file. Sorry for my english.

Comment: This was probably the reason, although removing the file and adding it again did not work. In the end I solved the problem by converting the original font file into another format.

Answer (score 0):

Its weird but I am guessing that the font files may be compressed wrongly by xcode. Check if xcode adds compression to font files as it does with image files. disable it and try to see if that solves the problem.